# My PC device appears twice in device list

Tags: ubuntu-one, tomboy, notes

I installed Ubuntu and I already have an Ubuntu One account. Then I go to the Ubuntu one application in Ubuntu and register my existing account. At this time Tomboy Notes are not synchronized, so I go to Tomboy preferences and set up the synchronize server to Tomboy Web, and Tomboy asks for web authorization... then I synchronize notes but my machine gets listed twice in the device list, but with different names.... I think Ubuntu One should know about my notes and synchronize them automatically... in Ubuntu One setup application I do not see any Note option for doing that.

How do i get only one machine configured? At this time I have My PC registered for files and contacts and another machine (the same physical machine) only for notes

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a device listed multiple times is perfectly normal, it only means you logged in twice. If you want, you can remove the "extra" device from the Ubuntu One website.